# import special module error

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I am using python2.7.6. When I run this order:

```
import scipy.special as S
```

I get this error:

```
 File "/home/liaoya/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 546, in <module>
 from ._ufuncs import *
 ImportError: libifport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: What OS?  How did you install Python and SciPy?

Comment: The OS is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server. I am a common user in this server, so I installed python on my home path. Python and scipy are all installed by compiling the source code.